# How to fix error in catching exception on call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, exception, xdebug

Assuming:

$name is not existing, and $args is not empty

```
try() {
    $results = call_user_func_array($name, $args);
} catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Catched!'
}
```

Expected:

```
prints "Catched!"
```

Results:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: Unable to call
```

Comment: `$name` doesn't look like a call-back function.

Comment: do some checks first, call_user_func_array doesn't throw an exception your have to validate first like `if (!is_scalar($name)){` and `if(!is_array($args)){`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran let say call-back function is not existing or mispelled

Comment: @LozCherone yeah got your idea tnx!

Comment: @javinc: Use `is_callable()` or `method_exists()`.

Comment: @AmalMurali I used class_exist() since I am using namespace